# How to make NSArrayController preservesSelection work for custom object?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, appkit, nsarraycontroller

I have a Cocoa app with a view-based table view bound to an `NSArrayController` with a list of custom `Employee` objects.

The table view shows the list of employees. In a subview, the employee's details can be changed.

Everything is set up, so that when an employee's details are changed, the table view contents are reloaded, showing the changes. So far, so good.

Now `NSArrayController` has the ability to preserve the selected object across reloads via `preservesSelection`.

For my custom Employee objects, this does not work. I assume because the array controller can't figure out how to match the old selected employee object from the old content to the new content after the list was updated.

I overrode `isEqual:` in my custom `Employee` class, but that's never called.

The docs just say about `NSArrayController.preservesSelection`:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver will attempt to preserve the current selection when the content changes

So how exactly does the array controller attempt to preserve the selection? It must compare the old selected object to the list of new objects somehow...

Comment: You shouldn't have to reload the data to show the changes in the details (unless your custom class isn't KVO compliant). Do you reload all data to display the changes in one row?

Comment: Overriding `isEqual:` should work. I can't tell from here why it isn't called. Did you bind `selectionIndexes` of the table view to the array controller? Do you set the content of the array controller or do you call `reloadData` on the table view?

Comment: @Willeke yes, I bound `selectionIndexes`. When my list changes, I reassign the full list like so: `self.employees = loadEmployees()`.

Comment: Which object is `self` and how is `self.employees` related to the content of the array controller?

Comment: `self` is the view controller which defines: `dynamic private var employees = [Employee]()`, this is bound to the contents array in Interface Builder.

Comment: There is [additional verbiage here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlSelection.html).  Would be nice if they mentioned `isEqual` rather than `attempt to find matching objects`.