# How to maintain TableView selection with "Handles Content As Compound Value"

Tags: xcode, macos, checkbox, binding, nstableview

I have an issue maintaining the selection on an `NSTableView`. I am using xCode 8.3.3 with Swift 3.1 and building for macOS.

The cell-based tableView is created in IB and has an `NSButtonCell` (a checkbox) in the first column of the table. This column is bound to `ModifiersController.arrangedObjects.enabled`. The checkbox functions as expected meaning it can properly be checked and unchecked.

The problem is that when I change the state of the checkbox by clicking on it, the selected row becomes unselected and the first row becomes selected. No matter which row is selected when I change the checkbox, it is always the first row that becomes selected.

What I expect to happen is that checking/unchecking the box should not affect the selected rows (highlighting).

[image]

The ArrayController is named 'ModifiersController', and its `Content Array` is bound to a `User Defaults Controller` key named `MinimizeModifiers`. The `MinimizeModifiers` is a dictionary of values with a custom `Value Transformer`. Because of this I have enabled the checkbox for **Handles Content As Compound Value**

[image: arraycontroller_bindings]

When *Handles Content As Compound Value* is **off** (disabled), the selection in the table is properly maintained, but the underlying code (bindings to UserDefaults) does not work.

When *Handles Content As Compound Value* is **on**, the UI element values are properly bound to UserDefaults, however, **this is what appears to cause the table to lose the current selection**.

So, the question is:
How can I maintain table row selection when *Handles Content As Compound Value* is enabled?

**Addendum**

The tableView is bound to `selectionIndexes` and the array controller is set to `preserve selection` (I have also tried with `preserve selection` off, and with 'Avoid empty selection' both on and off - without success).

[image: selectionIndexes_bind]

[image: arraycontroller_preserve]

And a link to mini movie showing the issue (if allowed)...
https://www.rgbworld.com/images/stackoverflow/selection.m4v

**Addendum2**

I have updated the code to Xcode 9 and Swift 4 and the problem persists. I believe the issue may have to do with my use of KVO and/or use of backing variables for use with my `@objc dynamic var`s

I have created a github repository in case someone can help. I am going to add a bounty for the dev who helps me resolve this issue.

**Githib Repo**

https://github.com/rgbworld/CompoundTransformer
https://github.com/rgbworld/CompoundTransformer

Comment: Did you bind 'Selection Indexes' of the table view to the array controller? Is 'Preserve Selection' switched on?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for reply. Yes and Yes. I have updated question to show settings.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue but clicking on a checkbox doesn't trigger saving the data. Something weird is going on, when I tried to find out how the table view handles the selection, I ended up in the same methods as with this question [How to make NSArrayController preservesSelection work for custom object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233759/how-to-make-nsarraycontroller-preservesselection-work-for-custom-object).

Comment: @Willeke I have added a bounty and a github repo. Hoping you may be interested in helping find a solution :-)

Comment: Did you try overriding `isEqual(_:)`?

Comment: @Willeke. That works! I figured it yesterday. The strangest thing is that I converted the code from Objective-C and `isEqual(_:)` was not overridden yet somehow it was working prior to OS 10.13. Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of the checkbox triggers the User Defaults Controller to save the data. The change in the user defaults triggers a refresh of the table view. The selected row isn't restored.

Solution: Implement `isEqual(_:)` in `ModifiersRuleTransformer`.

More info: [How to make NSArrayController preservesSelection work for custom object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233759/how-to-make-nsarraycontroller-preservesselection-work-for-custom-object)